# List Comparison in Python

Tags: python

I have my 2 lists like this:

```
list1=['A','B'] 
list2=['A','C','D']
```

I want to make comparison between two list two find out missing, additional and no change in entries, I am accessing it like this:

```
set1=set(list1)
set2=set(list2)

MissingName=set1.difference(set2)
AdditionalName=set2.difference(set1)
```

This gives me missing and additional entries, How can I find No change, which should be A??

Comment: What do you mean by "No change"?

Comment: Does the number of counts of a given element in each list matter?

Comment: What do you expect `if list1=['A', 'B']` and `list2=['A', 'A', 'B']`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for [set.intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
>>> list1=['A','B']
>>> list2=['A','C','D']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c1=Counter(list1)
>>> c2=Counter(list2)
>>> c1-c2 # missing items
Counter({'B': 1})
>>> c2-c1 # additional items
Counter({'C': 1, 'D': 1})
>>> c2&c1 # intersection
Counter({'A': 1})
```

---

The benefit of using the `Counter` class is that, unlike using `set`, it will work in cases where multiplicity matters, e.g.:

```
>>> Counter(['A', 'A', 'B']) - Counter(['A', 'B'])
Counter({'A': 1})
```

Also, you don't have to use such clunky method names :-)

Comment: @jamylak: not if multiplicity matters, and the OP's example doesn't detail if we're supposed to distinguish between `['A', 'B']` and `['A', 'A', 'B']`.

Comment: @DSM I just inferred from the wording of the question that OP wouldn't care about multiplicity but now that I think about it that example is worth mentioning in this answer

Comment: I don't get the point about the method names.  You can `&`, `-`, `^`, and `|` sets too.

Comment: @DSM Yes, that's what I was trying to say.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thought that comment attached to "The benefit of.."  I get what you mean now.  (I kind of like the full method names, though..)

Answer (score 0):

```
additional_entries_in_first = set1 - set2

additional_entries_in_second = set2 - set1

are_lists_equal = list1 == list2

are_element_sets_equal = set1 == set2

all_items = set1 | set2

shared_items = set1 & set2
```

Need anything more?